# How to iterate from the JPA query in spring boot based on the virtual table such as (the count of students for courses tutorials taken)

Tags: spring-boot, arraylist, spring-data-jpa, foreach-object

I need to retrieve each student with number of courses taken, for example :

| count | student |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | John |
| 8 | Jenny |

And I need the following JSON response from my rest end-point:

```
[
    {
        "name_student": John,
        "count_course": 5,
    },
    {
        "name_student": Jenny,
       "count_course": 8,
       
    },
]
```

I have made the query to fetch the required data inside the Repository:

```
@Query(value ="Select count(*), s.student_name from student s INNER JOIN courses c on c.student_id= s.student_id  group by s.student_name", nativeQuery = true ) 

List<StudentDTO> getIncidentCountByOfficerKPI ()
```

*My DTO:*

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentDTO {
    Integer count;
    String StudentName;
}
```

*Service:*

```
public List<StudentDTO> getStudentCount() {
    return p2StudentRepository.getIncidentCountByOfficerKPI ();
}
```

*Controller:*

```
@GetMapping("/Student-count")
public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> getAllStudentCount() {
    
    List<StudentDTO> selectedCount = p2StudentService.getStudentCount();
    List<StudentDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
    selectedCount.forEach(i -> {
        StudentDTOitem = new StudentDTO();
        item.setUserName(i.getStudentName());
        item.setCount(i.getCount());
        result.add(item);
    });
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

when I test with postman, it returns to nothing like below

```
[]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: you need to use  return new ResponseEntity<>(result,HttpStatus.OK); instead of 
ResponseEntity.ok(result); Before writing this debug the application and ensure you are getting records in result variable.

Comment: The code you've posted should raise a compilation error, which should be provided in the question. You can any response with it. Please update the Question (use *edit* button or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74822893/edit)) and add the code from your Controller which gives you an empty JSON-array as a response.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your rest end-point is incorrect, it should be `ResponseEntity<List<StudentDTO>>` (since you need to place multiple StudentDTO in the response).

And to provide `ResponseEntity` with a response body, you can use [`body()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder.html#body(T)) method of the `ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder` (*that's a builder-object produced by the static method* `ResponseEntity.ok()`), or it can be done by using of the [parameterized constructors of the `ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#%3Cinit%3E(T,org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode)).

And since you're actually not transforming the data returned by `getStudentCount()` you can attach this list as the response body directly.

```
@GetMapping("/Student-count")
public ResponseEntity<List<StudentDTO>> getAllStudentCount() { // <- change the return type
    
    List<StudentDTO> selectedCount = p2StudentService.getStudentCount();
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .body(selectedCount); // <- add the response body
}
```

Comment: Output is the same as our results which are empty lists [].

Comment: @AOSB That shouldn't be the case unless your repository returns an empty list. Did you try to debug? At least print the list from the controller, if `getStudentCount()` annotated with `@Query`, then you need to make sure that query does what expected (test it against your database manually).